# HTTP headers showing in browser when using J HTTP server

Tags: http-headers, j

I expect to see the regular JHS welcome page, but this is what I get instead:

[image: jhs distinctly not okay]

- I thought it might be issues with J itself, but jconsole works (as you can see in the console output preceding the `jhs` command)
- I thought it might be some localhost issues, but Python HTTP server works:

[image: python is okay]

My OS is Chrome 37 stable, and I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 in a chroot via [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/).

More Chrome info:

> **Google Chrome:**    37.0.2062.120 (Official Build 6b29c9a)
>
> **Platform:** 5978.98.1 (Official Build) stable-channel daisy
>
> **Blink:**    537.36 (@6894b21)
>
> **JavaScript:**   V8 3.27.34.17
>
> **Flash:**    15.0.0.152-r1

## Strangest part

JHS *was* working correctly before I reverted my OS from the dev channel back to the stable channel. To revert, I had to do what Chrome calls a "powerwash" which wipes all user data (including the chroot) and so I'm now coming from a fresh install. My best guess is that there is some library somewhere that I need to install, but I have no idea what it could be. And the fact that other things work correctly makes it all the more confusing.

#### Output of JVERSION (in case it helps):

```
Engine: j701/2011-02-23/15:25
Library: 8.03.05
Platform: Linux 32
Installer: J803 install
InstallPath: /home/lex/j803
```

Comment: Probably doesn't help too much, but works for me fine on Ubunutu 14.04. My JVERSION results are: `Engine: j701/2011-01-10/11:25,
Library: 8.03.05, Platform: Linux 64, Installer: J803 install, InstallPath: /opt/j64_803`
My id/jhs addon version is 1.0.208

Comment: I tried to repeat the process on OSX 10.9.5 and when I browsed to `http://127.0.0.1:65001/jijx` I was met with a "please install the labs" sort of message. When I viewed the source for the page it was, if I recall correctly, the same as what I'm currently getting in Ubuntu/ChromeOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Need to install labs first!

Found someone else with the same issue [on the J mailing list](http://jsoftware.com/pipermail/general/2014-August/036250.html). Subsequent replies pointed me in the right direction. But for the impatient, here is my `jconsole` session showing how to fix this issue on Linux. Probably also on OSX.

```
   load 'pacman'
   'update' jpkg ''
   'update' jpkg ''
Updating server catalog...
Local JAL information was last updated: 25 Sep 2014 20:23:43
Installed addons are up to date, 82 addons are not yet installed.
The base library is up to date.
   'showinstalled' jpkg ''
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┬────────────────────┐
│base library│8.3.5  │8.3.5  │base library scripts│
├────────────┼───────┼───────┼────────────────────┤
│ide/jhs     │1.0.208│1.0.208│JHS IDE             │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┴────────────────────┘
   'search' jpkg 'labs'
┌─────────┬┬──────┬────┐
│labs/labs││1.0.75│LABS│
└─────────┴┴──────┴────┘
   'install' jpkg 'labs/labs'
Installing 1 package
Downloading labs/labs...
Installing labs/labs...
Done.
Installed addons are up to date, 81 addons are not yet installed.
The base library is up to date.
   'showinstalled'jpkg''
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┬────────────────────┐
│base library│8.3.5  │8.3.5  │base library scripts│
├────────────┼───────┼───────┼────────────────────┤
│ide/jhs     │1.0.208│1.0.208│JHS IDE             │
├────────────┼───────┼───────┼────────────────────┤
│labs/labs   │1.0.75 │1.0.75 │LABS                │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┴────────────────────┘
   exit''
```

Now you can start `jhs` normally and it loads correctly.